# Remove a directory from git locally

Tags: git, git-svn

I am creating my working directory using this git command:
    git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git WebKit

Is it possible to remove a directory and its subdirectories locally and yet it won't screw up my future 'git svn rebase' when I try to sync up to a newer version of webkit?

Thank you.

Comment: You created a git working directory using a git command from a git repository, right? I don't understand where Subversion comes into this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use git rm --cached  to remove a directory locally. This will remove the files from version control.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the directory and its files from your local repository using `git rm` and committing the change.

When you next want to rebase against the upstream branch, you will have no problems if the upstream has not made any changes to those files you have removed. You changes can be applied without any interactive attention.

However, if the upstream has modified any of those files, `git rebase` will show a conflict and ask you what to do. When this happens, you can resolve the conflict by removing the file(s) in conflict and continuing the rebase. When you complete the rebase, those files will still be removed in your local repository.